# Why declaring multiple string arrays in one line cause initialized values to be messed up

Tags: arrays, c, initialization, undefined-behavior, c-strings

I am declaring two arrays in my code without initializing them:

```
    char verbe[27],
         radical[27],
         termi[6][4] = { "e", "es", "e", "ons", "ez", "ent" },
         pronom[6][10] = { "Je", "Tu", "Il/elle", "Nous", "Vous", "Ils/elles" };
        
    printf("entrer un verbe\n");
    scanf("%s", verbe);
       
    strncpy(radical, verbe, strlen(verbe)-2);
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%s", pronom[i]);
        printf(" %s", radical);
        printf("%s", termi[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

when my input for verbe[] is `manger`, it prints:

```
Je mang\376e
Tu mang\376es
Il/elle mang\376e
Nous mang\376ons
Vous mang\376ez
Ils/elles mang\376ent
```

I can't figure out where that `\376` comes from as it's supposed to print.

If I initialize `verbe[]` and `radical[]` as empty it prints the right result which is:

```
 Je mange
 Tu manges
 Il/elle mange
 Nous mangons
 Vous mangez
 Ils/elles mangent
```

Comment: Undefined behaviour — anything can happen.  Don't try to use undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The code snippet has undefined behavior because the arrays if they are declared in a block scope are uninitialized and you may not call printf

```
printf("%s ", B);
```

for uninitialized arrays.

This call expects that a passed array contains a string.

`EDIT:` After you changed your question cardinally then the array radical after the call of strncpy

```
strncpy(radical, verbe, strlen(verbe)-2);
```

does not contain a string. So this call

```
printf(" %s",radical);
```

again invokes undefined behavior.

You need to write at least like

```
strncpy(radical, verbe, strlen(verbe)-2);
radical[ strlen(verbe)-2 ] = '\0';
```

Comment: I just fixed the question please check it out

Comment: @DevX It is a bad idea because such cardinal changes of the question only confuse readers of the question a and answers.

Comment: @DevX See my appended post.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the surprising output is you use `strncpy` to extract the verb from the input line: `strncpy(radical, verbe, strlen(verbe)-2);`.

`strncpy` is a false friend, it does not do what you think it does. As used in your code fragment, it copies all but the last 2 bytes in the input line, presumably to strip the `er` at the end of the verb of the first group.

The problem is it does **not** add a null terminator after the bytes it copied because there is no such terminator in the part of the source string it copied. Hence the rest of the `radical` array is unchanged and since it is not initialized, it still contains whatever garbage is present in memory at the time your function is called. In your case there happens to be a byte with the value `0xFE` and a null byte at offsets 5 and 6 of the `radical` array, but anything else could happen on your computer or any other computer. This is called undefined behavior, and the consequences are unpredictable.

My advice is to **never** use `strncpy`. You can learn why on this page: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

For your purpose, you can use a different technique: you can set a null terminator explicitly to strip the last 2 letters from the verb, after checking that it has indeed at least 3 letters and ends with `er`.

Note also that `manger` is not a fully regular verb: the first person plural spells `nous mangeons` instead of `nous mangons` which would be pronounced differently and be meaningless.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char verbe[27];
    char radical[27];
    int len;
    char termi[6][4] = { "e", "es", "e", "ons", "ez", "ent" };
    char pronom[6][10] = { "Je", "Tu", "Il/elle", "Nous", "Vous", "Ils/elles" };
        
    printf("Entrer un verbe: ");
    if (scanf("%26s", verbe) != 1) {
        printf("fin de fichier inattendue\n");
        return 1;
    }
    len = strlen(verbe);
    if (len < 3) {
        printf("verbe trop court: %s\n", verbe);
        return 1;
    }
    if (verbe[len - 2] != 'e' || verbe[len - 1] != 'r') {
        printf("pas un verbe du premier groupe: %s\n", verbe);
        return 1;
    }
    strcpy(radical, verbe);
    radical[len - 2] = '\0';
        
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("%s", pronom[i]);
        printf(" %s", radical);
        if (i == 3 && radical[len - 3] == 'g') {
            printf("e");
        }
        printf("%s", termi[i]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
Entrer un verbe: manger
je mange
tu manges
il/elle mange
nous mangeons
vous mangez
ils/elles mangent
```

Of course French is full of special cases, for example:

```
Entrer un verbe: aimer
je aime
tu aimes
il/elle aime
nous aimons
vous aimez
ils/elles aiment
```

the first person singular should be `j'aime`

```
Entrer un verbe: placer
je place
tu places
il/elle place
nous placons
vous placez
ils/elles placent
```

The first person plural should be `nous plaçons`

And many other exceptions, even for the first group:

- jeter  -> je jette
- péter  -> je pète
- régler -> je règle
- appeler -> j'appelle
- marteler -> je martèle
- dépuceler -> je dépucelle, mais plus moderne: je dépucèle... vive l'Académie
- habiter -> j'habite
- harponner -> je harponne
- yoper -> je yope
- aller -> je vais (pas officiellement du premier groupe)

Check this site for reference: https://leconjugueur.lefigaro.fr/conjugaison/verbe/

Comment: thank you so much, but I have noticed another thing regarding these lines of code

Comment: When I initialize these 2 arrays this way char verbe[27];
    char radical[27];  and I add printf(" %d", strlen(radical)); after using the strncpy in my code in the post. it prints different results for the length of radical[] when its initialized with the size 27 and when its initialized with 33 in the size. If my input is "manger" the length of radical is 6 when it's size is 27, and it's 4 when the size of radical is 32. Can you please explain  this difference ?

Comment: `strncpy(radical, verbe, strlen(verbe)-2);` only copies the letters `mang` and does not set a null terminator after the `g` in the destination array `radical`.  `radical` is a local array, it is uninitialized, so its contents can be anything when the function is called, which explains why `strlen(radical)` does not necessarily stop after the `g`... it will keep examining the contents of `radical` until it finds a null byte, which may or may not be present before the end of the array. `strncpy` is error prone, DO NOT USE IT.

Comment: What does that have to do with the size of the array radical, why the length of the string radical (for 'manger' as input) changes from 6 to 4 when I change the size of the array radical from 27 to 33?

Comment: Because undefined behavior is undefined... the behavior you observe is a side effect of circumstances for which the C language defines nothing. Changing the lengths of these arrays changes the layout in memory so the contents of uninitialized arrays may change... None of this is predictable and may change from one run to another